# Not receiving OTA update after restore stock rom from cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, stock-android, ota-update, 5.1-lollipop

I heard Moto G2 was getting a `Lollipop 5.1` update so I decided to go back to stock from cyanogenmod. I used a tutorial similar [to this one](http://www.droidviews.com/restore-moto-g-2014-to-stock-and-lock-the-bootloader/) to go back to stock, and I'm now currently on `Lollipop 5.0.2` with system version `22.21.28`. The issue is I'm not getting the system update (already tried with motorola device maganer in my PC)

Browsing the web I found this info (the one with bold letters) on [this website](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/development/rom-stock-rom-t2970427)

> this flashes the newest system and boot image:
>   22.21.28-titan_retuglb.zip flash via custom recovery
>
> **for completeness the corresponding modem and recovery for this system version.
>   (This doesnt add any functionality, but allows you to install future ota's)**
>
> **xt1063-22.21.28-modem.zip flash via custom recovery**
>
> **xt1063-22.21.28-recovery.img flash via fastboot**

Which made me think this might be the solution but after checking what I did to go back stock, I already had flashed a `recovery` and a `modem`.

Why can't I get OTAs, did I miss to flash something? is this recovery and modem file different from the ones I already flashed (see tutorial) and using these ones is the solution?

Comment: Isn't this OTA update available to download from other sources? E.g. I can update my OPO by downloading OTA update from OnePlus Forums and then flash it via Stock/Custom Recovery. In this way I don't have to invest my time thinking why my phone isn't getting update. Just an alternative. :)

Comment: I suppose, but I'd rather not having to flash stuff on cli anymore, I'm slowly turning into a end-user hahaha.

Comment: @Firelord at any case, is there a place to download the image so I can flash it? (an official place, if  possible)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any official place for Moto G2. All I can think of is their support website. You may ask them for such. It shouldn't be a big deal for them to provide it. Good luck. :)